# Global Variable in Javascript for Laravel Routes - Is this a good idea?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vue.js

I've created some code using a View Composer where I am passing my Route Collection through to the front end on all views, so I can access all of my laravel routes in Vuejs via the route named associated with them.

For example, to upload an image using a vue component, instead of passing my upload route into the Vue Component, it is listed as a part of a global variable:

```
var uploadRoute     = _.find(globalRoutes, function(route) { return route.name == 'route-name.image.upload' });
$.post(uploadRoute, data) ... etc
```

My question is...is this sensible? I'm publically publishing my entire app's routes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think your hunch about exposing your entire apps routes is legit. IMO you should explicitly pick out the routes that you need. So in thise case, you should only expose `route-name.image.upload`. You could create a tiny helper function to look up routes and output them along with the URL as JSON.

```
function json_routes(array $routes)
{
   $return = [];

   foreach($routes as $route)
   {
       $return[$route] = route($route);
   }

   return new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(json_encode($return));

}
```

And the, in your main view:

```
var routes = {{ json_routes(["route-name.image.upload"]) }};
```

Getting a route is simple:

```
routes['route-name.image.upload'];
```

**This is the most basic exaple I can think of. You can optimize it quite a bit. Just some ideas:**

- Place the routes in a central place, fx. a config element: `json_routes(config('app.json_routes'))`
- Build a command that generates a static `.json` file so that you don't iterate through the routes on each page load. Remember to re-generate when you add more routes.
- Create a function instead of an object to get the route. That allows you to build in logic and gives a more Laravel-like feel in your js: `function route(path){ return window.routes.hasOwnProperty(path) ? window.routes[path] : null ;}`
- **(Advanced)** Re-write Laravels router logic and hook into the options array, allowing you to do something like `Route::get('dashboard', '...', ['as'=>'dashboard', 'expose'=>true]);`, then dynamically generate the before mentioned json-file on all routes with the `expose` option.

Comment: I like the advanced suggestion - I might try that.

Comment: @Ed That'd also circumvent the hazzle of having to update your route array manually if you change the routes name.

Comment: Yeah, I've tied it into a gulp task that watches the route file for any changes and then that fires a command via artisan to compile the exposed routes. Easy! Thanks again!